# How to make ROI line in open cv movable or let user draw it with his mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

i am using [this](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/vehicle_counting_tensorflow) as base for making a better vehicle counter but the roi line is hard coded in the middle of the screen: `cv.line(input_frame, (0, int(height/2)), (int (width), int(height/2)), (0, 0xFF, 0), 5)`
like this and i am looking for a way two make it dynamic or by letting user draw which if find only tutorials and answers for [rectangles](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/) or make it movable by mouse clicks for going up and down in the screen.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: but i know where to start i know exactly what element i need to change but i only find way to change or draw rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/?fbclid=IwAR3T6gGQBw6dGzgoTcPDM9VBsuMVIKSJsSJge8rPtGexPN0B56ocjZWh5Gc) 
You need to capture your mouse coordinates and then use cv.line

```
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
# grab references to the global variables
global refPt, cropping

# if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
# (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
# performed
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    refPt = [(x, y)]
    cropping = True

# check to see if the left mouse button was released
elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    # record the ending (x, y) coordinates and indicate that
    # the cropping operation is finished
    # y = height x = width
    refPt.append((x, y))
    cropping = False
    # draw a rectangle around the region of interest
    #cv.line(input_frame, (0, int(height/2)), (int (width), int(height/2)), (0, 0xFF, 0), 5)
    cv2.line(image,(0, int(y)), (int(width), int(y)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what i was looking for.